# C++ wrong letter for output

Tags: c++

Hello I have new question about Caesar cipher for example

Key:    3

Plain:  ABCÇDEFGĞHIİJKLMNOÖPRSŞTUÜVYZ

Cipher: DEFGĞHIİJKLMNOÖPRSŞTUÜVYZABCD

These are Turkish letters " ç ,ı ,ğ, ö , ş , ü , Ç, İ , Ğ, Ö, Ş, Ü  "

I need to make encryption and decryption and program shouldnt have case sensitive. It should be like s=S, ç=Ç

You can see my program below ,but I have some problems

1) Text(Plain) and key should entered by user but I couldnt do it.

2) char text[] = "DEF";   this input should give (for decrypt) "CÇD"  but it gives "CÃD"

normally it should give "Ç" instead of "Ã"

I need help :(

```
# include <iostream>
# include <cstring>

const char alphabet[] ={'A', 'B', 'C', 'Ç', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'Ğ', 'H', 'I',
                        'İ', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'Ö', 'P', 'R', 'S',
                        'Ş', 'T', 'U', 'Ü', 'V', 'Y', 'Z', '0', '1', '2', '3',
                        '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '.', ',', ':', ';', ' '};
const int char_num =44;

void cipher(char word[], int count, int key)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i < count) {
        int ind = -1;
        while(alphabet[++ind] != word[i]) ;
        ind += key;
        if(ind >= char_num)
            ind -= char_num;
        word[i] = alphabet[ind];
        ++i;
    }
}

void decipher(char word[], int count, int key)
{
    int i = 0;
        while(i < count) {
        int ind = -1;
        while(alphabet[++ind] != word[i]) ;
        ind -= key;
        if(ind < 0)
            ind += char_num;
        word[i] = alphabet[ind];
        ++i;
    }
}


int main()
{
    char text[] = "ABC";
    int len = strlen(text);
    std::cout << text << std::endl;
    cipher(text, len, 2);
    std::cout << text << std::endl;
    decipher(text, len, 2);
    std::cout << text << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "1) Text and key should entered by user but I coulndt it because I gave error all time" <- That is NOT a helpful description of your problem.

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: The problem is not the code. It's that the console you are printing to has not been set up to handle Unicode characters. The Unicode value for Ç is 199, but in DOS 199 prints as Ã.

Comment: Yeah, the "easy solution" would be to set your local code page to somehow tell the compiler that both input and output should be code page 1254, and then tell all your users to set their local code page to code page 1254 before running your code.  Obviously, the "easy solution" is a bad idea.

Comment: I am new at programming so these comments weird for me what should I do with 1254 :D .

Answer (score 1):

This issue is that your program is using a different encoding than the one the console expects. Windows is configured this way by default; programs use encodings like cp1252 or cp1254 and the console expects something else like cp437.

[Here's](http://www.siao2.com/2005/02/08/369197.aspx) an article from a Microsoft developer that explains why this is.

There's already a lot of information online covering the numerous ways you can fix the encoding mismatch.

Comment: I am beginner so I couldnt get it what u mean with cp1254 :(  I need to use or obtain Turkish charachters with using a c++ code.