# C++ gives an error

Tags: c++

Hello I have an error at this program that is  wcout is not a member of `std'.   Also I used  iostream as you see but didnt work.I have Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2 and my operating system is XP SP3
I need your help.
Thanks for free time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cwchar>
using namespace std;
const wchar_t alphabet[] ={'A', 'B', 'C', 'Ç', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'Ğ', 'H', 'I',
                        'İ', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'Ö', 'P', 'R', 'S',
                        'Ş', 'T', 'U', 'Ü', 'V', 'Y', 'Z', '0', '1', '2', '3',
                        '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '.', ',', ':', ';', ' '};
const int char_num =44;

void cipher(wchar_t word[], int count, int key)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i < count) {
        int ind = -1;
        while(alphabet[++ind] != word[i]) ;
        ind += key;
        if(ind >= char_num)
            ind -= char_num;
        word[i] = alphabet[ind];
        ++i;
    }
}

void decipher(wchar_t word[], int count, int key)
{
    int i = 0;
        while(i < count) {
        int ind = -1;
        while(alphabet[++ind] != word[i]) ;
        ind -= key;
        if(ind < 0)
            ind += char_num;
        word[i] = alphabet[ind];
        ++i;
    }
}

int main()
{
    wchar_t text[] = L"ABJT;";
    int len = wcslen(text);
    std::wcout << text << std::endl;
    cipher(text, len, 2);
    std::wcout << text << std::endl;
    decipher(text, len, 2);
    std::wcout << text << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a more recent version of [dev-c++ with mingw](http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/files/Portable%20Releases/)?

Comment: I tried now and same problem :(

Comment: Did you uninstall the old version first before trying the new one? I just tested it and it compiles fine for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ wrong letter for output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576061/c-wrong-letter-for-output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2 that you're using comes with MinGW-gcc 3.4.2 which is [7+ years old](http://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html), likely doesn't have wide-chars properly supported as suggested by sftrabbit.

If you look at the top of the original [Dev-C++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dev-cpp/) at sourceforge you'll see that its been superseded by [Orwell Dev-C++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp). I would suggest using that if you need wide-char support since it packages a much more recent version of MinGW-gcc.

Answer (score 4):

If you're compiling with MinGW, [wide characters are not yet supported](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/wide_characters). If you really need it, an alternative is to use the [STLPort](http://www.stlport.org/) library as an alternative to libstdc++.

Comment: Funny, both `wcout` and `wstring` have worked for as long as I can remember with my MinGW.

Comment: @chris Perhaps it has been recently ported and the asker is using an old version? That page hasn't been updated though.

Comment: Probably. I've noticed parts of the MinGW site not being maintained in the past.